# WPF RepeatButton content alignment?

Tags: wpf, alignment, repeatbutton

I have a repeatbutton in WPF. The height of buttun is set to 10 because of the space limitation. Now the content of the repeatbutton is not displaying because, I think, the alignment of the content has some problem.

I am wondering is there any way to change the alignment of the content so that it can show up even when the height of the repeatbutton is small?

Here is my xaml:

```
<RepeatButton Name="ABPPlus" Height="10" Click="btnABPPlus_Click"  Content="+" 
    Delay="500" Interval="100" Width="30"/>
```

Comment: can you show your XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    <Button Height="10" Width="50"  >
        <Button.Content>
            <Canvas>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Top="-7" >fff</TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this will fix your issue, but in order to rotate the `Content` of your `RepeatButton`, you should use a `RotateTransform` on it. Try this:

```
<RepeatButton Name="ABPPlus" Height="10" Click="btnABPPlus_Click" Delay="500" 
    Interval="100" Width="30">
    <TextBlock Text="+">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" /> 
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</RepeatButton>
```

A better solution would just be to use a smaller `FontSize`:

```
<RepeatButton Name="ABPPlus" Height="10" Click="btnABPPlus_Click"  Content="+" 
    Delay="500" Interval="100" Width="30" FontSize="10" />
```

Comment: The + does not quite show up. The bottom part is still blocked unless the height of the repeatbutton is changed to 12. And I have another button which has a - sign does not show up at all....

Comment: Thanks. I am upvoting your answer because it could be a solution. Thanks for your help!